# Ionic searchbar decrease margin at the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am developing a web app with Ionic/Angular. Now I want to implement a searchbar, but it has too much margin at the bottom. How can I decrease the margin? You can see my problem at the picture. The preview is on an iPhone SE2.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there are 2 things causing that. Margin under searchbar and the padding around your list. you can set `padding-top: 0` to your list. it will do the work.